# 802.1x authentication over wireless not wired

Tags: windows-xp, authentication, wifi, ethernet, 802.1

We have a wireless network that authenticates via 802.1x free-radius server.  We have told the wireless network to authenticate accordingly and it works.  However when we have a wired network we have to uncheck the "authenticate to 802.1x" box (In our novell client) and then we can log in fine.  Does anyone know a way to allow for seamless decision making when authenticating.  We don't want users to have to have to remember to check or uncheck a box based on where they are.

Set-up:
XP SP3
Novell 4.91 SP5
Authenicate Via free-radius wirelessly
NO 802.1x authentication via wire

Thanks.

Comment: Do the networks have the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it a while ago, just forgot to post it.  We played with the bindings on the ethernet devices.  We ordered so that the wireless goes first then the wired.  You will still get an 802.1x error but it will then turn over to the wired and log in just fine.